# Change location of vim yankring history file

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, yank

The yankring plugin for Vim creates a file in my home directory called yankring_history_v2.txt.  How do I tell the plugin to store this file in another location?

Comment: I've opened a PR to address this issue on the original YankRing repo.  Doesn't look like it's maintained, last PR was 4 years ago.  But I didn't see a better-maintained repo. https://github.com/vim-scripts/YankRing.vim/pull/16

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yankring looks for a variable called yankring_history_dir to know where to store this file.  Add the following line to your .vimrc:

```
let g:yankring_history_dir = 'path/to/history/dir'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also change the file's name with `yankring_history_file`. For example, if you want it to be a hidden file in your home directory, leave `yankring_history_dir` as-is, and add this to your .`vimrc`:

```
let g:yankring_history_file = '.yankring_history'
```